# Magento: How to resize catalog and product image while image is uploading?

Tags: image, resize, magento

About catalog images I found smth here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/resizing-catalog-images/.

But it has a path *Design > Themes Editor > Customize (Theme) > Catalog Images* that I haven't in my admin panel.

As for product images I haven't any idea how to resize image.

I will be grateful for any link and tips.

PS: I read out that image resize is used in the template file directly. If we have 100 images per page it means that Magento resizes 100 times per page loading. Seems it require a lot of additional resources.

Comment: Not really, resized images are stored in media/catalog/product/cache

Comment: When we reload cache is it updated? or is it updated only after page reolad?

Comment: The image cache is never cleared, unless you manually click Flush Catalog Images Cache.

Comment: FYI. The linked article is only for Magento Go which is probably why you cannot match it's instructions to your Magento Community store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're going about this the wrong way. It is always best to retain the highest quality version. Let's say right now you want to shrink images to 300x300. What happens next year when you redesign you site and you want to feature product images more prominently and you want 400x400 images? You can't because you only have 300x300. As already mentioned, Magento has an resize mechanism that does exactly what you want. It will resize (shrink) the images once and store them in a cache. The first time that image is loaded then Magento does the resize and any subsequent image load will load the already saved image from the cache. Voila, you have both the original high quality image stored and the resized image stored.

Comment: Thx for your detail response. I see now. I imagined it differently before. It does not concern the current question but if we have different sizes of one image we can store original HR size and any time we need do resize of main image. In this case we don't need cache for images at all? I wonder that Magento doesn't use this way.

Comment: Yes, Magento lets you store multiple images per product. You can store different images, even if they are different sized versions of the same image, and display them each where you need them. But again, what happens when you want to make an update to the product image? You have to update every sized version. There is nothing wrong with using an image cache, it is a very smart practice.